# AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to generate the Access_Token after generating the Authorization code using MS Graph API.

I am getting the following error (Screen shot below)

"error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.",

I see that grant_type is present. I checked the rest of the values to be without any spaces. Any ideas on what could be wrong here? I appreciate your support.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: try switching the body to send using "form-data" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try once in [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to explicitly add the 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in the Headers tab in case you haven't already.